# Get single byte in clickhouse. Canno get very simple query work

Tags: yandex, clickhouse

The query `SELECT splitByChar('x,y', ',');` says

> Received exception from server (version 1.1.54385): Code: 0.
>   DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, ::1. DB::Exception:
>   Illegal separator for function splitByChar. Must be exactly one byte.

What the hell does he want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT splitByChar(',', 'x,y');
```

Separator is the first argument. 
[Doc](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single/#splitbycharseparator-s)